# Woocommerse minicart widget button hover overlay

Tags: css

Everyone,

I am a newbie in WordPress (working on localhost). I want to change the hover color of WooCommerce mini cart widget button.

I have written the following code:

```
.widget_shopping_cart .button {
  margin:0.5em 0 0;
  width:100%;
  background: white !important;
}
.widget_shopping_cart .button:hover {
  width:100%;
  background: white !important;
}
```

It works, though when I hover over the button `(background color set to white)` though I get the grey overlay on top (regardless my selected hover background color). This is totally bugging me as it ruins my selected color by making it dirtier (darker). How can I get rid of it? I am using flat some theme.

Comment: Can you provide more code? There may be an opacity effect added on hover, are there pseudoelements on the button?

Comment: I have as well written custom CSS for featured products button. hope it helps:

.add_to_cart_button  {
 color: #360797 !important;
 background-color: white !important;
 border-color: purple !important
}
 
.add_to_cart_button:hover{
 background-color: #f4b035 !important;
 color: black !important;

This opacity effect is active by default but only on mini-cart widget and it is removed on featured products slider (checked with default settings)

Answer (score 0):

```
.widget_shopping_cart .button:hover {
  width:100%;
  background: white !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

set the css property box-shadow to none and you are good